# Бесконечное развертывание на устройство Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, развертывание, xamarin.android

Я зеленый новичок в Xamarin. У меня есть Sample App которое называется AndroidApp1 (скачано с мануала по Xamarin Live Player). Я его пару дней назад дебажил, все было нормально. В [репозитории](https://github.com/VictorGorban/Something-went-wrong-here-with-Xamarin.Android) в bin/debug есть apk.

После чего появилась проблема: Я попробовал уменьшить размер приложения, сконфигурировал release, и в какой-то момент у меня вылезла ошибка типа "data/local/tmp/AndroidApp1.AndroidApp1 уже есть на устройстве". У меня рутированный телефон, я зашел в эту папку, не увидел там упоминания AndroidApp1. И удалил папку tmp. Попытался снова запустить deploy, вылезла deploy error Permission denied. Создал папку. Снова Permission denied. Установил разрешения к этой папке rwxrwxrwx (чтобы точно не промахнуться). Теперь у меня бесконечный deploy, причем в этой папке (tmp) apk появляется. И я могу его установить.

На телефоне стоит программа RootBrowser. Я так понимаю, не стоило удалять эту папку. Но все же, что мне теперь делать?

Это действительно бесконечный deploy, уже полчаса идет.

Comment: А комп не слабый? У меня первый деплой минут 15 занял. Потом быстро. Как правило, он долго Депортиво моно машину. может, в этой папке были к ней относящиеся файлы и он ее заново устанавливает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что ж, проблема, решилась обновлением файловой системы. Через заводской сброс телефона.